# running out of memory building massive string

Tags: c#

I have a program that converts a byte[] to a string of hex:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(infile);

try
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(BitConverter.ToString(bytes)); // <--exception 
    hexfield.Text = sb.ToString();  
}

catch(Exception e) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString()); 
}
```

This works fine for most case. But when I use a huge file, for example a 103 MB .flv video file it runs out of memory it throws an exception:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
at System.String.CtorCharArrayStartLength(Char[] value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
at System.BitConverter.ToString(Byte[] value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
at System.BitConverter.ToString(Byte[] value)
 at shex.shexx.hexfield_Dragrop(Object sender, DragEventArgs e)**
```

Comment: What do you need to do with readed bytes?

Comment: The real question ofcourse is: WHY. You cannot possibly usefully assign that value to an input control (assuming hexfield is one). You should simply truncate it to the useful amount.

Comment: @sll with the bytes or the hex string? The question states: `"a program that converts a byte[] to a string of hex"`

Comment: What's wrong with `File.ReadAllText()` method?

Comment: @ShadowWizard The file is binary data, not text, so the bytes in the file shouldn't be interpreted as characters in a particular encoding which is what `File.ReadAllText()` would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BitConverter.ToString` method first creates a `char` array, then creates a string from that, so you would need room for the string twice in memory.

You can convert the data in smaller chunks, and create the `StringBuilder` with an initial size so that it has all the room it needs. This way the large string exists only once in memory:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 3 - 1);
int pos = 0;
while (pos < bytes.Length - 1000) {
  b.Append(BitConverter.ToString(bytes, pos, 1000)).Append('-');
  pos += 1000;
}
b.Append(BitConverter.ToString(bytes, pos));
hexfield.Text = b.ToString();
```

However, note the comment from sehe about the usefulness of such a huge string. The best solution might actually be to not create the entire string at all.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the BinaryReader to read the file in parts and add each part to the stringbuilder instead of reading the whole file at once and converting it to a string.

Have a look at [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Well then don't feed `BitConverter.ToString` such large arrays. Do it in chunks of, say, 1 MB per time.

Use a [`BinaryReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered streaming, for example? It depends on what you want to do with that string, if you are sending it which is the most likely scenario when you can send it in small portions which is what streaming is for. Some protocol implementations also allow to construct a chuck and the flush it, so I would suggest that way to go.

In your case you can read only some part of file and then analyze it. Checkout BinaryReader, FileStream classes and streaming in general